# collector in Activity does not always trigger

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

So I have this in an onCreate in an activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.state.collect() { state ->
                    println(state)
                    when (state) {
                        MyViewModel.State.First -> launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                                replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, FirstFragment())
                            }
                        }
                        MyViewModel.State.Second -> launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                                replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, SecondFragment())
                            }
                        }
                        MyViewModel.State.Init -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and in the viewmodel I have a stateflow

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    enum class State {
        First,
        Second,
        Init; }
    val state = MutableStateFlow(State.Init)
    fun goToFirst() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            println("go to first")
            state.emit(State.First)
        }
    }
    fun goToSecond() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            println("go to second")
            state.emit(State.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

the app displays the list fragment and I can add and remove users its great... until the list is empty. The activity stops collecting from the stateflow and never switches to the empty. Its gets weird though. In the viewModel, as an experiment, I added

```kotlin
init {
   while (isActive) {
        delay(1000)
        state.emit(State.First)
        delay(1000)
        state.emit(State.Second)
   }
}
```

and it switches back forth between fragments. It just doesn't switch to the empty state fragment when I use the buttons on the screen to clear the list. I've tried using SharedFlow and I've tried using a stateflow of an enum class that had two vales list and empty. Samething. The collector in the activity doesn't fire everytime. I know about conflation. the values are different. I've tried almost every combination of Dispatchers and add in a coroutine exception handler to every launch that never catches anything. I've also tried using globalscope. Why doesn't the collector in the activity fire everytime a different value is emitted?

Comment: Can you check your code? It looks like code from inside a `when` block, but the `when` call is missing. Maybe you removed too much before pasting it here. Without seeing the actual code, it's hard to say what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a viewModel factory in the activity and in the fragments. So the fragment would call a function it's viewmodel to change the state, but the viewmodel the activity was listening to never sent any state change.